# Link to Area51's search instead of just home page from "404 Not Found" for unknown SE sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51, 404-not-found

I go to "http://testing.stackexchange.com/"

**Happens:**

It shows me "Site not found ... You can vote for it to be created through our democratic, community-driven process at [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)..." (a generic link to Area51)

**I want:**

It shows me "Site not found ... You can vote for it to be created through our democratic, community-driven process at [area51.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=testing)..." (a link to search results for "testing")